# Segmentation fault C en Dev C++

Tags: c, dev-c++

Quería saber si alguien me podría ayudar con este error en mi código. No entiendo por qué no continúa después de que el contador tome el valor de 10.

Éste es mi código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
int main() {
    int Nalumnos, cont;
    Nalumnos=0;cont=0;
    int x[Nalumnos];
    scanf("%d",&Nalumnos);

    do{
    cont=cont+1;
    x[cont]=cont;
    printf("Alumno numero %d\n",x[cont]);

    }while(cont<Nalumnos);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: En que consta el programa? que tiene que hacer?

Answer (score 5):

```
int Nalumnos;
Nalumnos=0;
int x[Nalumnos];
```

¿Has visto alguna vez en matemáticas un vector de tamaño 0? Declarar un vector, en tu caso `x`, con tamaño 0 no va a ser jamás una buena idea.

Deberías probar a intercambiar la declaración de `x` y la línea siguiente, que es donde inicializas `Nalumnos`:

```
scanf("%d",&Nalumnos);
int x[Nalumnos];
```

Y, por favor, para próximas consultas procura no poner el código dentro de una imagen ya que así es imposible copiar tu código y hay que reescribirlo. Con este tipo de prácticas consigues que la gente pierda el interés por responderte.

Un saludo.

Comment: Si no me equivoco dependiendo del compilador y del estándar que se quiera seguir, es posible que no se puedan declarar variables después de realizar operaciones... aunque en el código original de OP parece que eso no era un problema, pero podría ser un fallo que alguien encontrase

Comment: Si mal no recuerdo el estándar C99 ya permite estas operaciones y es un estándar que tiene ya casi 20 años...

Comment: Ok, deja que reescriba mi comentario: "cuando aprendi a programar, no se podían declarar variables después de...". De repente me siento viejo :P

Comment: jajajaja. Este tipo de cosas son un poco follón, sobretodo si andas compaginando C con C++....

Answer (score 1):

Tu error está cuanto intentas declarar `int x[Nalumnos];` ya que en ese punto `Nalumnos` es cero. Puedes ponder la declaración después del scanf que es cuando sabes el tamaño del arreglo pero si quieres declarar la variable antes puedes apartar memoria y después liberarla.

```
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    int Nalumnos, cont;
    Nalumnos=0;cont=0;
    int *x;
    scanf("%d",&Nalumnos);
    x = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int)*Nalumnos);

    do{
        cont=cont+1;
        x[cont]=cont;
        printf("Alumno numero %d\n",x[cont]);

    }while(cont<Nalumnos);

    free(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: La respuesta no es correcta porque no has indicado el tamaño del tipo int al reservar la memoria... por lo que reservarás espacio para `Nalumnos` de tipo char. Por otro lado, desde el estándar C99 (que data de 1999) se pueden crear arrays de tamaño variable en la pila, lo que evita el uso de `malloc` y `free` y las posibles fugas de memoria.

Comment: Tienes razón, ya está corregido

Comment: Vale... ahora estás reservando espacio para un único int, ya que `sizeof(Nalumnos)==sizeof(int)`... lo que tu estás buscando es `Nalumnos*sizeof(Nalumnos)`. También se podría dejar como `Nalumnos*sizeof(int)`, pero si cambiases el tipo de `Nalumnos` te tocaría modificar la reserva de memoria a mano para que todo siguiese funcionando.

Comment: Give a break dude! corredigo! otra vez